# Play Video button

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger play function of the video. . Can you suggest the javasript function to play this video ?

jsfiddle code is given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/X3fcA/2/). To play the video I need to rightclick the video and they click play function of flashplayer. 
I have the below video code in html:

```
<div class="content flowplayer is-splash is-closeable" id="vid1">
    <video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.webm" tabindex="0">    
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.webm"></source>
</video>    
</div>
```

Comment: What research have you performed? What did the documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have update your code. [It's working now.](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/X3fcA/3/)

You have to get element's id of tag `video` and then just say `.play()`

More example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop).

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the video element (e.g. by giving it an id then using `document.getElementById`), then call [the `play()` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#dom-media-play) on it.

Comment: I tried, it tells .play is not function. can you show me the example for .play() function ?

Comment: @Umesh — Then `foo` is not a `<video>` (or your browser doesn't support `<video>`).